# Struct with initially invalid fields

Tags: c#, struct

I'm trying to create a struct that has two fields that I can check for being valid/invalid directly after creation. since the two fields are `0` by default, I'd like to check them for being invalid if they are `-1` ...

```
public struct InputCodeSet
{
    public int primary;
    public int secondary;


    public InputCodeSet(int primary = -1, int secondary = -1)
    {
        this.primary = primary;
        this.secondary = secondary;
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return primary > -1 && primary < InputCode.MAX && secondary > -1 && secondary < InputCode.MAX; }
    }
}
```

However testing any created `InputCodeSet` results in `IsValid` always being true after creation, even if a primary or secondary wasn't set. Obviously the default values in optional constructor parameters are being ignored? Any other ways to get this working? I'd like to use mainly object initializer syntax with them ...

```
var inputCode1 = new InputCodeSet { primary = InputCode.55 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; continue it in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180669/discussion-on-question-by-badmintoncat-struct-with-initially-invalid-fields).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Structs have separate default parameterless constructors that, when called, do not invoke the constructor overloads with parameters, even if all parameters are optional. Thus, creating a struct without passing any arguments to its constructor invokes its default constructor and causes its fields to be initialized as 0, ignoring your constructor with optional parameters entirely.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs):

> If you instantiate a struct object using the default, parameterless constructor, all members are assigned according to their default values.

Perhaps you could make these fields nullable and check for null instead of -1:

```
public struct InputCodeSet
{
    public int? primary;
    public int? secondary;

    public InputCodeSet(int? primary = null, int? secondary = null)
    {
        this.primary = primary;
        this.secondary = secondary;
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return primary != null && primary < InputCode.MAX && secondary != null && secondary < InputCode.MAX; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. This was an informative answer. +1

Comment: @BoltClock Didn't know I can make them nullable in NET 4. This might work but IsValid returns False in every case.

Comment: @BadmintonCat: Both `new InputCodeSet(1, 2).IsValid` (using your constructor) and `new InputCodeSet { primary = 1, secondary = 2 }.IsValid` (using initializer syntax) return true for me.

Comment: @BoltClock Ok, got it working now as per your example. Thanks a lot!